# magento 2 after adding multiple currency, sales order in admin showing two currencies

Tags: magento2, configuration, sales-order, currency

I have two currencies set - Ruppes and USD. 
Ruppes is my base currency.

I am facing problem is - USD orders in admin sales shows both currencies as shown in below image:

What can be done to show only one USD currency(and not rupees) when USD order is placed.

Is there any currency setting in admin where it can be handled? or Any extension?? Any Idea to solve this problem.

[image: Order placed with USD]

Comment: `Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Currency Setup` : `Base Currency` & `Default Display Currency` is Same? Try to make it same.

Comment: yes Base Currency & Default Display Currency  is same

Comment: `Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> "Catalog" > "Price" > "Catalog Price Scope" should be "Global". Please check Magento CE 2.1.3 with Sample Data. By default its working fine.

Comment: I checked with it. its set to "Global". and version i am using is Magento CE 2.1.0

Comment: So please try to disable other third party extension

Comment: I have added AutoCurrency by IP address extension  from http://blog.chapagain.com.np/auto-currency-switcher-2-magento-2-extension-free/ for autocurrency by ip. But it has not overridden any admin sales order where it can show both currency. Disabling this module will end with only one currency

Comment: Good. Finally u got it where is issue.

Comment: No I dint got any solution. I mean to say was - The Extention -  Autocurrency I used for auto switching currency based on IP.  In that  nothing that they have overridden then still why two currencies in admin order for USD.

Comment: @SPK did u get any solution fr this?